# Is the term 'everyday people' derogatory?

Tags: word-choice

I came across the term 'everyday people' in an unpublished essay. It strikes me as derogatory just because it is referring to people rather than to things and makes them appear common. But then there is 'common people' or 'commoners' to contend with, so I'm not very sure.

It was used like this:

> Everyday people trooped to the theatre to see the show.

Okay, so here is the exact sentence in its original context (it's from a short book review):

> The book is brimming with stories of everyday people who in spite of
> the curves life threw at them were able to come up strong and better.

What is the authoritative word on this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an attempt at the frequency adverbial usage? << Every day,  people trooped to the theatre to see the show. >> Standalone, the use of adjectival  'everyday' sounds unnatural rather than dismissive in this sentence. Is it licensed by prior context? _Prior context is needed here._ As also is some clue as to whether the essay ewas written by a Professor of Linguistics, Orwell, or a man on a Clapham omnibus.

Comment: If kosher, 'Everyday People: managing to find the extraordinary in everyone' (an 'early' non-propriety example in a Google search) and from [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/specials/cnn-heroes), 
'Everyday people doing extraordinary things to change the world'. seem quite laudatory contextualisations.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, no there is no comma there nor does it seem intended.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth wouldn't it read just as well to say ordinary people? My e-dictionary says "Everyday" means "Found in the ordinary course of events," "Appropriate for ordinary or routine occasions" and "Commonplace and ordinary." I won't like very much to add it to "people."

Comment: You haven't given details expected on ELU. How can we judge whether it's a typo, a pure error in word-choice,  an avant-garde usage ...? The two quotes I mention above should offend nobody. (Perhaps I should avoid 'nobody'? [in one sense, 'saying in an unkind way that the person is not at all important.']) // 'Ordinary' has at least the same degree of pejorative connotation. 'Every man and his dog' is perhaps sexist nowadays.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I've said in the comments that there was no comma omitted (I guess my judgement cannot be trusted). To remove all doubt, I only wanted to know if some people might raise an eyebrow at the word choice itself seeing as the dictionary definitions always use it to qualify things and never persons, and just the way it always seems to intentionally diminish (and not even in a bad way) the thing it qualifies. I think that as soon as one uses 'everyday' to qualify people, it becomes a tad condescending. Would you say it has a high degree of the pejorative connotation you mentioned?

Comment: Btw, I have now edited the question to include the full context.

Comment: No, it's not derogatory.

Comment: https://youtu.be/3JvkaUvB-ec

Comment: This sentence is _far_ better than that originally posted. ' ... stories of everyday people' sounds totally natural and non-pejorative. CED gives the sense 'typical'. One can usually find an alternative definition that's not really helpful. And context is extremely important; "Typical!" is dismissive, rude. 'The common man' vs "You're so common!"

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I just wanted to use it in a sense that would clearly show that no comma was intended. And I didn't want to put out the snippet online because it's unpublished. I guess I didn't pick the best sentence for my example. Thanks for bearing with me and your answer.

Comment: @HotLicks & Mitch, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess context is the only thing that can really give the answer. *Everyday people* can also be used as an opposite of *pretentious people* or *snobs*, in which case it is anything but derogatory I would say.

If you really want to avoid 'everyday', you could replace it by expressions like, *Normally/in normal circumstances people...*. Of course, I say this trying to guess the context, so do forgive me if it is not relevant to your particular sentence.

Comment: I'd added the context, thanks.

Comment: The original context is clearly not derogatory. It is definitely an eulogy of those who, although they are not privileged in life, can live through anything. I personally think the use of 'everyday people' is excellent here.

Comment: That's cool, thanks @fev

Answer (score 0):

A word will be derogatory if either the speaker (or writer) uses the word with the intent of being derogatory, or the hearer (or reader) interprets it in a way they see as derogatory.  If a person sees him or herself as being above others in value or quality they would use “everyday people” as a derogatory phrase.

One issue we run into is that society is often that which determines whether or not a word is derogatory.  At one point in time, the “n-word” was used, at times, without any derogatory intent (some certainly used it in a demeaning way, but not all).  Over time though, that word became pretty well accepted as an inappropriate, derogatory word – even if it was spoken with no demeaning intent.

As society moves toward ‘politically correct’ labels, I can see where the same will hold true for “everyday people”.  Over time, I can see where people will say, “whether you intended it or not, that’s derogatory – no one is more or less common (or everyday) than anyone else.”

Answer (score -1):

Mm, you see *everyday people* next to *trooped* does give you the hint of a trace of contempt or irony. Could it be that it is intended to be so? If you want to make it more neutral I would find a synonym of *trooped* (like *gathered, crowded in*, etc). Or how about

> All kinds of people trooped to the theatre to see the show.